# How to use Dash.js without video controls

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, mpeg-dash

I want to use DASH for a background video, i.e. one without a "Player", I want it to auto play and loop, without a pause button, or control bar at the bottom. 
How do I do this? At the moment, I am just using the default implementation:

```
<script src="http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/dash.all.js"></script>
<body onLoad="Dash.createAll()">
     <div>
         <video class="dashjs-player" autoplay preload="none" controls="true">
            <source src="http://dash.edgesuite.net/envivio/Envivio-dash2/manifest.mpd" type="application/dash+xml"/>
         </video>
    </div>
</body>
```

Alternatively, is there any documentation for this that I could read?

Comment: how about `controls="false"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try setting `controls` value to false?

Answer (score 1):

You must omit the `controls` keyword.
Setting `controls="false"` doesn't work, at least not in the latest DASH.js version 2.7.0.

-Arjen